# Inline-block DIVs fill table cell in Chrome, but not other browsers?

Tags: css, css-tables

I have a small issue. After figuring out how to get some DIVs nested inside of a table cell to all fit at 100%, depending on the height of the table row, I noticed it doesn't work in Firefox or IE. Instead of trying to explain, here's the page: http://www.faganarms.com/testcategory.aspx

[image]

I'm trying to get all of the cells in each row to expand to be the height of that row, depending on it's content. If one row has very small descriptions, it might be shorter in height than one with long descriptions. You'll notice in FF or IE the behavior I'm looking to correct.

The problem is, I can only edit some part of the HTML, others I can only style with CSS. I can edit the contents of `td.product-list-item-container` but I cannot edit the structure of that table. It's hard coded into the software.

Does anybody see what the issue is? I've tried some methods I found here on using `display: table-row` and `display: table`, but nothing has worked as successfully as this does, in Chrome at least. I couldn't find anything about the method that was Webkit compatible only, so I might be missing something.

Comment: I deleted it minutes after because I made some changes in the developer tools of Firefox and it worked! However, I lost it and now I can't seem to replicate the solution. I disabled some styles and it ended up making all the cells even in height, and all I had to do was add padding to the DIVs and it worked. I thought I removed the inline-block from the table rows to fix it, but I can't replicate it again. Ughhh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed `display: inline-block` and all padding from the table rows, added `height: 100%` to the table rows and `div.product-list-item`, and added the padding onto `div.product-list-item` and it worked fine in FF now.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `min-height` CSS property and set it to the height of one row! You should do this for the div class "product-list-item". Now the div will take this height as minimum, or just set the height to the height you want.